# Linkedin accesstoken oauth call error

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get the linkedin accesstoken from authorize code. I get from the https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization. But when i send the resquest from the accesstoken to the url

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?code=AQTxKjDnKVK8bhxJf10fHE8kEfGh9APlnGTRXyrNMLx-RkZ_EEKfvpx1YRMlhsr5R_qdNlxZ1DUqZR0xCkZe_4hIl_Ih8d1x3_sdf0xqjMu6lp2Ny48&client_id=75g9zob6m8cpzi&client_secret=gsEVhrKzrByUwPOy&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcallback%3Fsite%3Dlinkedin&grant_type=authorization_code
i am getting error when i make http get request from in angular js. I am able to get access token when i make request through the **postman** or **browser**
my console error is

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access
```

Comment: Have you ever fixed this problem ? I am having same problem with my jquery ajax

Comment: LinkedIn does not support for the cross origin. I have used the javascript sdk to get token.